# what is the meaning of following xml axis abbreviated clause

Tags: sql-server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/path-expressions-using-abbreviated-syntax

the following is from above link can anybody provide me with the example of the below representation.

For example, in the following query, the use of a dot represents a value and not a node:

```
("abc", "cde")[. > "b"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @xml xml = N'<t>
    <abc />
    <cde />
    <fgh />
</t>'

SELECT @xml.query('("abc", "cde")[. > "b"]')
```

- `("abc", "cde")` - from only nodes `abc` and `cde`
- `[. > "b"]` - select nodes that are greater than string `"b"`

Chnage `"b"` to `"ab"` and see the difference, or add node `fgh` to the list.

Comment: is there any relation exits between the elements assigned to @xml variable

Comment: is there any relation exits between the elements assigned to @xml variable and elements written in side the query() function?

Comment: @user3129097 yes, `abc` and `cde` are nodes from xml

Comment: @user3129097 how is my answer? Do you need something else?